# Reading numbers from text and order the numbers

Tags: c, file

Complete task:

> Write a program that reads from a text file 10 integer numbers. The
>   file has to be previously created using a different code or by using
>   the operating system’s facilities. Write the functions that:
>   - order the integers array in ascending/descending order and displays the result
>   - count the number of even numbers in the array and display the result

My code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
void cresc(int citire[20]);
FILE *fpointer;
void main()
{


    char fisier[12];
    int  i,citire[20];
    printf("Dati un nume fisierului:");
    scanf("%s", &fisier);
    strcat(fisier, ".txt");
    fpointer = fopen(fisier, "w");
    fprintf(fpointer, "9865742031");


    fclose(fpointer);

    fpointer = fopen(fisier, "r");
    for (i = 0;i < 9;i++)
        fscanf(fpointer, "%d", &citire[i]);
    fclose(fpointer);


    fpointer = fopen(fisier, "a+");
    fprintf(fpointer,"\nNumerele puse in ordine sunt: \n");
    cresc(citire);

    fclose(fpointer);


    _getch();
}

void cresc(int citire[20])
{
        int i,temp;
        for (i = 0;i < 9; i++)
        {
    if (citire[i] > citire[i + 1])

            {
            temp = citire[i];
                citire[i] = citire[i + 1];
                citire[i + 1] = temp;

            }
    fprintf(fpointer, "%d", citire[i]);
        }
}
```

Can someone help me?

I manage to solve it, thanks for your help guys.

Here is the problem solved, if someone will need it.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

FILE *fpointer;
void cit(int citire[10]);
int paritate(int citire[10]);
void main()
{


    char fisier[12];
    int  i, citire[10], trecere[10], nrpar;
    printf("Dati un nume fisierului:");
    scanf("%s", &fisier);
    strcat(fisier, ".txt");
    fpointer = fopen(fisier, "w");
    fprintf(fpointer, "9 8 6 5 7 4 2 0 3 1");


    fclose(fpointer);

    fpointer = fopen(fisier, "r");
    for (i = 0;i < 10;i++)
        fscanf(fpointer, "%d", &citire[i]);
    fclose(fpointer);


    fpointer = fopen(fisier, "a");
    fprintf(fpointer, "\nNumerele puse in ordine sunt: \n");
    cit(citire);

    nrpar = paritate(citire);
    fprintf(fpointer, "\n\nSunt %d numere pare", nrpar);

    fclose(fpointer);


    _getch();
}

void cit(int citire[10])
{

    int  i,j, temp;
    for (i = 0;i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0;j<9;j++)
            if (citire[j] > citire[j + 1])

            {
                temp = citire[j];
                citire[j] = citire[j + 1];  //9 8 6 5 7 4 2 0 3 1
                citire[j + 1] = temp;           //buble sort

            }
    }
    for (i = 0;i < 10; i++)

        fprintf(fpointer, " %d", citire[i]);
}

int paritate(int citire[10])
{
    int i, par=0;
for (i = 0;i < 10; i++)
    if (citire[i] % 2 == 0)
        par ++;
return par;


}
```

Comment: Check `fscanf()`'s return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wright a string representing a single value to the file, you then read `9` integers from the file but there is a single value. You need to separate the values with a non numerical character, like this

```
fprintf(fpointer, "9 8 6 5 7 4 2 0 3 1");
```

and then to read, do this instead

```
while ((i < 9) && (fscanf(fpointer, "%d", &citire[i]) == 1))
    ++i;
```

Fix your `cresc()` function to make it take the number of elements as a parameter

```
void cresc(int *citire, int count);
```

and the for `loop`

```
for (i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
```

In your `main()` call `cesc()` like this

```
cresc(citere, i);
```